# Need advice on how to make chain link shape

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make this chain:

[image]

[image]

The general shape of the link is like this:

[image]

I just need some direction on how to make this shape as its giving me a bit of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a simple shape 3x mirrored:

[image]

Once done, apply the mirror so that you can rotate the shape and add an array modifier (I was not able to find a way without applying the mirror):

[image]

[image]